# Generate syntax-colored, hyperlinked source code from Haskell or Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, haskell

Are there any packages that can take a directory full of source code (Objective-C and Haskell are the ones that interest me) and generate syntax-colored HTML from it where function names are links to their source code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For haskell you can take a look at Haddock:

http://www.haskell.org/haddock/